# How to dynamically bind variable when using scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain

Tags: scala, interpreter

I'm trying to implement a class evaluating the result of given scala script and input value and print the result of evaluation with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain. Here's my test code.

```
package some.test.package

import javax.script.{Compilable, CompiledScript}

import scala.tools.nsc.Settings
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.{IMain, JPrintWriter}

class Evaluator {

  // Create IMain instance when created
  val settings = new Settings()
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  val writer = new JPrintWriter(Console.out, true)
  val engine = new IMain(settings, writer)
  val compiler = engine.asInstanceOf[Compilable]

  var inputVal : Int = _
  var compiledObj : CompiledScript = _

  // compile given script
  def compileScript(givenCode : String) {
    compiledObj = compiler.compile(givenCode)
  }

  // evaluate
  def evalCompiled(): Unit = {
    compiledObj.eval()
  }

  // set input value
  def setInput(givenInput:Int) {
    inputVal = givenInput
  }

  // bind input variable
  def bindInput() {
    engine.bind("inputVal", "Int", inputVal)
  }

}

object IMainTest {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    // create an instance
    val evaluator = new Evaluator()

    // first set input value to 3 and do evaluation
    evaluator.setInput(3)
    evaluator.bindInput()
    evaluator.compileScript("def f(x:Int):Int=x+1; println(f(inputVal))")
    evaluator.evalCompiled()

    // let's change input value and re-evaluate
    evaluator.setInput(5)
    evaluator.evalCompiled()

  }
}
```

My expectation was the program prints out '4' and '6' but the result was '4' and '4' printed out.

So, my question is...

1. Does IMain.bind just copies value not reference to some place that the engine can refer to?
2. Should I compile every time when I want to re-assign value of variable?
3. If the answer for 1 and 2 is 'YES', then is there any other way that I can achieve my purpose without re-bind and re-compile? I just expected re-assigning input value does not need additional bind operation or compile operation.

I think it's really hard to find IMain related examples or documents so any reference links might be also very helpful for me. Thank you.